# Why does using Linker in Xamarin slows down application in release build?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin-linker

Having used Linker in Xamarin to reduce the size of the release build of my android application, after having installed the application. The application runs much slower in the release build as compared to when I am debugging the application in debug mode.

- No error is reported and the application runs without crashing apart from the fact that the application has slowed down.

Creating a release build without using the linker does not result in the application slowing down.

This is a bit confusing as I believe that Linker is meant to reduce the application size and not affect application performance.

Is there an explanation for this kind of scenario?